# Remove All To Addresses from Apache HtmlEmail

Tags: java, email, memory, apache-commons

So initially I was coding a marketing email application that send emails to thousands of recipients. I was naively doing something like this:

```
for(all emails)
{
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setBody(theHtml);
    email.addTo(currentEmail);
    email.send();
}
```

The issue with the above is that after so many emails, the garbage collector has to kick in and remove the stale HtmlEmail objects which eats up a bunch of CPU. I am now trying to do something like below:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setBody(theHtml);

for(all emails)
{
    //Option1: Use below line of code but need to remove the previous "current email"; that is, not send this to all the previous recipients AND the new one
    //Line to remove previous email from HtmlEmail object
    email.addTo(currentEmail, currentName);
    //or option 2: email.setTo(new String[]{currentEmail});
}
```

The uncommented method's issue is that addTo does not remove previous added email addresses. I certainly do not want to send the same emails to the same recipients. VERY VERY DISASTROUS. So if I do that method, I would need a way of removing the previous email. I want to do something like

```
email.setTo(Arrays.asList(new String[]{}));
```

The issue with this is that the api states that all containing strings must be valid email addresses or it will throw an exception. The other option would be to use `email.setTo` everytime, but then the recipients name cannot be included. Can anyone suggest a method to do one of the above? If you need clarification I understand that it is a little hard to put into words. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but it seems that HtmlEmail exposes the internal List in the getToAddresses() method. So a email.getToAddresses().clear() would actually clean out all recipients and you could then again use addTo().

But this relies on internals of the HtmlEmail class which is definitely not good coding practice.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for finding that. I took a look, and you are indeed correct. Weird API for sure.